# Почему не происходит заполнение переменной w?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

Массив w должен выводить некоторые рассчитанные коэффициенты, а выводит массив заполненный nan, как это можно исправить?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 40

trX = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)

num_coefs = 6
trY_coefs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
trY = 0

for i in range(num_coefs):
    trY += trY_coefs[i] * np.power(trX, i)

trY += np.random.randn(*trX.shape) * 1.5


tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32)
Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32)

def model(X, w):
    terms = []
    for i in range(num_coefs):
        term = tf.multiply(w[i], tf.pow(X, i))
        terms.append(term)
    return tf.add_n(terms)


w = tf.Variable([0.] * num_coefs, name="parametrs")
y_model = model(X, w)

cost = tf.square(tf.pow(Y - y_model, 2))
train_op = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    for (х, у) in zip(trX, trY):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: х, Y: у})

w_val = sess.run(w)
print(w_val)

sess.close()
```

Comment: Уберите отступ слева каждой строки, с ним любой код выдаст `IndentationError`.

Comment: В программе отступов нет, здесь так работает редактор

Comment: @иванвойтенко редактор тут нормально работает, нужно просто почитать справку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code